# aggregate multiple dataframe with overlapping timeseries

Tags: python, pandas

I have multiple dataframe with timeseries index in dfList.(example dataframe is shown below)
I tried to concatenate these dataframe into one dataframe by following command.

```
db=pd.concat(dfList)
```

and I got following dataframe.
[image]
Timeseries index are duplicated (many index are 2012-10-12 20:00:00) since timeseries in base dataframe was overlapping each other.
I want to remove this duplicate. Does anyone know how to do this?

some example dataframe in which timeseries index are overlapping is shown below

[image]

[image]

Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

You can simply drop the duplicates by a particular column value as mentioned [in the docs here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html). You may do something like this:

```
db = db.drop_duplicates(cols="Timestamp")
```

which will drop all rows with duplicates in the column "Timestamp" except the first occurrence.